# Zipping a file from a directory and placing it in another Directory

Tags: python-2.7, zip

I am trying to set up a program to put my minecraft server world into a zip and place it into another directory on another drive (/media/500gb/MinecraftWorldBackups) 
But I keep getting this error
[image]

Although the folder doesn't contain a folder or file called 'h'

[image]

What do I need to do to fix this I believe it is due to file and folder?

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
import time, zipfile

while True:
    FileName = 'MinecraftBackup_' + str(int(time.time()))
    Path =  '/home/bertie/Desktop/FeedTheBeastServer/world/' 
    print(FileName)
    Zip = zipfile.ZipFile('/media/500gb/MinecraftWorldBackups/'+FileName+'.zip','w')
    for each in Path:
        print(each)
        try: Zip.write(Path + each) 
        except IOError: None
    Zip.Close()
    print('Done')
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: You don't get the contents of a folder by iterating a string that happens to contain a path. You need to use something like `os.walk` - see http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-traverse-a-directory-tree-in-python-guide-to-os-walk/

Comment: Path is `/home/bertie/...`. `for each in Path` yields `/`, then `h`, then `o`, etc